# RxJava Android wait for callback to finish before returning data

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm new to RxJava. I have an Android app that is using AWS Cognito SDK for authentication. I have an `AwsAuthClient` class that handles calling the SDK and returning the results. I have a fragment that calls the `SignUp` method in `AwsAuthClient`. I need to return the results of signup to the fragment so that it can react appropriately.

RegisterFragment class:

```
public class RegisterFragment{
    AwsAuthClient authClient;

    public void onCreateAccountClick() {
        Subscription createSubscription = authClient.SignUp(params)
            .compose(Transformers.applyIoToMainSchedulers())
            .subscribe((CognitoUser currentUser) -> {
                transitionToVerificationScreen();
             }, (Throwable throwable) -> {
                 // Report the error.
             });
    }
}
```

Here is the AwsAuthClient:

```
public class AwsAuthClient {

    public void SignUp(CreateParams createParams){

        // Create a CognitoUserAttributes object and add user attributes
        CognitoUserAttributes userAttributes = new CognitoUserAttributes();

        // Add the user attributes. Attributes are added as key-value pairs
        // Adding user's given name.
        // Note that the key is "given_name" which is the OIDC claim for given name
        userAttributes.addAttribute("given_name", createParams.getFirstname() + " " + createParams.getLastname());

        // Adding user's phone number
        userAttributes.addAttribute("phone_number", createParams.getPhone());

        // Adding user's email address
        userAttributes.addAttribute("email", createParams.getPhone());

        SignUpHandler signupCallback = new SignUpHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(CognitoUser cognitoUser, boolean userConfirmed, CognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails cognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails) {
                // Sign-up was successful

                currentUser = cognitoUser;

                // Check if this user (cognitoUser) needs to be confirmed
                if(!userConfirmed) {
                    // This user must be confirmed and a confirmation code was sent to the user
                    // cognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails will indicate where the confirmation code was sent
                    // Get the confirmation code from user
                    Timber.d("Sent confirmation code");
                }
                else {
                    // The user has already been confirmed
                    Timber.d("User has already been confirmed.");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
                // Sign-up failed, check exception for the cause
            }
        };

        userPool.signUpInBackground(userId, password, userAttributes, null, signupCallback);
    }
}
```

How can I return the results of onSuccess or OnFailure up to the RegisterFragment class?

Comment: rxjava1 or rxjava2? Edit: nevermind... `Subscription` tells me it's rxjava1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Cognito SDK already provides an async way to get information. In order for you to wrap this into an rx stream, you should consider using a `Subject`.

`Subject` are both `Observable`s capable of emitting data, and `Observer`s capable of receiving data. A `Subject` can wait to receive the callback data, take the data, and then emit it onto a stream.

```
public Observable<CognitoUser> SignUp(CreateParams createParams){
    BehaviorSubject<CognitoUser> subject = BehaviorSubject.create();

    // ...

    SignUpHandler signupCallback = new SignUpHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(CognitoUser cognitoUser, boolean userConfirmed, CognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails cognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails) {
            // Sign-up was successful

            // Check if this user (cognitoUser) needs to be confirmed
            if(!userConfirmed) {
                // This user must be confirmed and a confirmation code was sent to the user
                // cognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails will indicate where the confirmation code was sent
                // Get the confirmation code from user
                Timber.d("Sent confirmation code");
            }
            else {
                // The user has already been confirmed
                Timber.d("User has already been confirmed.");
            }

            subject.onNext(cognitoUser);
            subject.onComplete();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
            subject.onError(exception);
        }
    };

    userPool.signUpInBackground(userId, password, userAttributes, null, signupCallback);
    return subject;
}
```

Comment: There is a problem with this solution:
you trigger your subject once you call this method and then return your subject to your user. Observables should be treated lazily triggered by the `subscribe()`. Before user subscribe, nothing should happen.

Comment: This is definitely a *hot* observable. There is no right or wrong on how observables should be treated as it is up to the developer to decide on [hot vs cold](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339). The reason `BehaviorSubject` was suggested here was exactly because this is a *hot* observable. :)

Comment: A method signature like this : `public Observable<CognitoUser> SignUp(CreateParams createParams)` it should be triggered once I subscribe , don't we?
It's true that subjects are `hot` observable. They could do whatever they want even there are no subscribers. But normally we want our Network called when we subscribed not when we call that `getObservable()` methode

Comment: Your solution's scenario is like : I called SignUp-> it call signUpInBackground -> once I subscribe to it -> I get the **replayed** value.
A normal case should be like : I called SignUp -> I get a Observable -> I subscribe to it -> it call signUpInBackground -> I get the SignUpValue.
Notice that your **replayed** value is not exactly what your called value, it can be you called this method twice and get a wrong value from it's replay value.

Comment: Imaging that you call your `signUp` method once, and get the OK result before your subscription. For whatever reason you call it second time but you lose your internet connection. You can only get the fail result for both of your call.

Comment: @PhoenixWang Can you provide an alternate solution for RxJava1?

Comment: @stackunderflows I edit my answer. You can just use `Observable.create(Action1>,BackPressureMode)` and it's basically the same `create` operator of RxJava 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using RxJava2. You can use the create() operator to create your own async call:

```
public class AwsAuthClient {

    public Observable<CognitoUser> SignUp(CreateParams createParams){
        return Observable.create(emitter -> {
            SignUpHandler signupCallback = new SignUpHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(CognitoUser cognitoUser, boolean userConfirmed, CognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails cognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails) {
                // Sign-up was successful
                emitter.onNext(cognitoUser);
                // Check if this user (cognitoUser) needs to be confirmed
                if(!userConfirmed) {
                // This user must be confirmed and a confirmation code was sent to the user
                // cognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails will indicate where the confirmation code was sent
                // Get the confirmation code from user
                Timber.d("Sent confirmation code");
                }
                else {
                    // The user has already been confirmed
                    Timber.d("User has already been confirmed.");
                }
                emitter.onComplete();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
                // Sign-up failed, check exception for the cause
                emitter.onError(exception);
            }
        };
        //cancel the call
        Observable.setCancellable(//your cancel code)
    })
}
```

Edit: If you are using RxJava1(latest version 1.3.2) you can just use Observable.create(Action1>,BackPressureMode) instead of create and it's ***safe***

```
        Observable.create(new Action1<Emitter<CognitoUser extends Object>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Emitter<CognitoUser> emitter) {
            SignUpHandler signupCallback = new SignUpHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(CognitoUser cognitoUser, boolean userConfirmed, CognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails cognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails) {
                    if (!userConfirmed) {
                        Timber.d("Sent confirmation code");
                    } else {
                        Timber.d("User has already been confirmed.");
                    }
                    emitter.onNext(cognitoUser);

                    emitter.onComplete();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
                    emitter.onError(exception);
                }
            };
            emitter.setCancellation(new Cancellable() {
                @Override
                public void cancel() throws Exception {
                    //Your Cancellation
                }
            });
            signUpInBackground(userId, password, userAttributes, null, signupCallback);
        }

        //Because RxJava 1 doesn't have Flowable so you need add backpressure by default.
    }, Emitter.BackpressureMode.NONE );
```

Comment: However in RxJava1 stay away from `create`! What's the equivalent of `create` in RxJava1?

Comment: @EugenPechanec yes. if you are using newer version of RxJava 1. There are overloads that can safely create you a Observable like RxJava2. ex: `Observable<T> create(Action1<Emitter<T>> emitter, Emitter.BackpressureMode backpressure)`

Comment: Since I'm using 1.X the other answer ended up working for me, but this is helpful to know for version 2.

Comment: @stackunderflows there are equivalent operator as the RxJava2 create in RxJava 1. But I can't really remember what was that. fromEmitter/fromAsync or something like that. And subjects should be used carefully as well.

Comment: @stackunderflows and with that subject solution, there are some problems. see the comment at that answer.

Comment: @PhoenixWang I tried to use your answer but it doesn't compile. It says "unexpected bound" when I hover over "extends".